# Wait for variable in NodeJS and Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using nodeJS. I want to wait for a property inside an object to become true, and then continue code execution.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
export async function createRun() {
    try {
        let shared = { url: "", device: "", finished: new Promise(() => {}) };

        const browser = await launch();

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

        await page.setBypassCSP(true);

        await page.exposeFunction(
            "onMessageReceivedEvent",
            async (e: { type: string; data: Message }) => {
                if (e.data === "finished") {
                    shared.finished = ;
                }
            }
        );

        const listenFor = (type: string) => {
            return page.evaluateOnNewDocument((type: any) => {
                window.addEventListener(type, (e) => {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    window.onMessageReceivedEvent({ type, data: e.data });
                });
            }, type);
        };

        await listenFor("message");

       console.log('before');
       // wait for shared.finished to become true
       // continue execution
       console.log('after')
}
```

How can this be implemented? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `page.waitForFunction` lets you block on an arbitrary predicate, but it's hard to say more than that because I'm not sure what condition you want to wait for or what you're trying to achieve here at a high-level. Which site are you working with? Can you add details and a runnable [mcve], please?

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to go this way, you can try something like this (sorry, I do not know TS):

```js
export async function createRun() {
    try {
        let resolver;
        let shared = { url: "", device: "", finished: new Promise((resolve) => { resolver = resolve; }) };

        const browser = await launch();

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

        await page.setBypassCSP(true);

        await page.exposeFunction(
            "onMessageReceivedEvent",
            async (e: { type: string; data: Message }) => {
                if (e.data === "finished") {
                    resolver();
                }
            }
        );

        const listenFor = (type: string) => {
            return page.evaluateOnNewDocument((type: any) => {
                window.addEventListener(type, (e) => {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    window.onMessageReceivedEvent({ type, data: e.data });
                });
            }, type);
        };

        await listenFor("message");

       console.log('before');
       await shared.finished;
       // continue execution
       console.log('after')
}
```

However, `page.waitForFunction()` can be simpler solution, as suggested in the comment.